# How do I return info from methods

Tags: c#

I want to get information from two methods (student and teacher) and send the info to another method PrintStudentDetails - to print to console - but how can I pass the strings to a print method ? I tried passing strings back but I could not get it to work ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace Assignment3
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            GetStudentInfo();

        //    PrintStudentDetails();
        }   

        static void GetStudentInfo()
        {
            // Get student details
          Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
          string sfirst = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name");
          string lastName = Console.ReadLine();
          Console.WriteLine("Enter the students birthday");
          string studentsBirthday = Console.ReadLine();

        }

        static void GetTeacherInfo()
        {
            // Code to get teacher name, course, program and degree
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the teachers first name: ");
            string teacherfirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name of course: ");
            string teacherlastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter program: ");
            string programName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Degree: ");
            string degreeName = Console.ReadLine();            
        }

        static void PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }            
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would have to use `return` type as `string` or any other datatype that you want to return value from a function.

Currently your functions are of `void` type. Meaning, they return nothing. If you want to get string value from a function, Declare it as a `string` type and return string value.

Something like :

```
static string GetTeacherInfo()
        {
            // Code to get teacher name, course, program and degree
            Console.WriteLine("Enter the teachers first name: ");
            string teacherfirstName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter name of course: ");
            string teacherlastName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter program: ");
            string programName = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine("Enter Degree: ");
            string degreeName = Console.ReadLine();            
            return degreeName;
        }
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: thanks ! thats it ! just one question, I want to return 3 strings but get Unreachable code detected when I have return teacherfirstName;
            return teacherlastName;
            return degreeName; after each other

Comment: 3 `return` statements wont work in single code block. Its because the execution is returned after it encounters the very first return statement. So  basically its one to one relation. One function - one return statement.

Comment: If you want to return all the 3 from one code block, you might want to concatenate them into single string or make an array of `string` type and return that.

Comment: No, string concatenation is awful. Instead use a data structure (e.g. a class, mapping, etc) to collect the individual strings into one object, and return that from the function.

Answer (score 2):

The typical way to do this is to *return* the collected data from the function using a `return` statement. Since you are collecting multiple data items you will need to bundle them up somehow.

One way to handle this is to use a `class` that has attributes for each of the data items, and then return a instance of that class from the function. (I'll show examples below for the student info; teacher info is analagous.) Something like this:

```
class StudentInfo
{
    public string firstName;
    public string lastName;
    public string birthday;
}
```

Your function `GetStudentInfo()` can then to create and return an instance of class `StudentInfo`:

```
static StudentInfo GetStudentInfo()
{
  // Get student details
  StudentInfo studentInfo = new StudentInfo();

  Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's first name: ");
  studentInfo.firstName = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the student's last name");
  studentInfo.lastName = Console.ReadLine();
  Console.WriteLine("Enter the students birthday");
  studentInfo.birthday = Console.ReadLine();

  return studentInfo;
}
```

Your print function can remain as is, requiring the caller to extract the attributes from the `StudentInfo` instance:

```
static void PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", first, last, birthday);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

Call it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StudentInfo studentInfo = GetStudentInfo();
    PrintStudentDetails(studentInfo.firstName, studentInfo.lastName, studentInfo.birthday);
}
```

Alternatively you can pass a `StudentInfo` directly to the print function:

```
static void PrintStudentDetails(StudentInfo info)
{
    Console.WriteLine("{0} {1} was born on: {2}", info.firstName, info.lastName, info.birthday);
    Console.ReadLine();
}
```

and call it like this:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StudentInfo studentInfo = GetStudentInfo();
    PrintStudentDetails(studentInfo);
}
```

or more simply without creating the intermediate `studentInfo` variable:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    PrintStudentDetails(GetStudentInfo());
}
```

Note that you can actually have both versions of `PrintStudentDetails()` available thanks to function overloading. C# will call the right function depending on the argument type:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    StudentInfo studentInfo = GetStudentInfo();
    // using separate arguments...
    PrintStudentDetails(studentInfo.firstName, studentInfo.lastName, studentInfo.birthday);

    // or passing a StudentInfo instance...
    PrintStudentDetails(GetStudentInfo());
}
```

Having said all that, there are other data structures that could be used to achieve the same effect as a class, e.g. a key/value mapping, a list, tuple or similar.

Answer (score 0):

Hi I guess your are following the EDX DEV2014x MOOC too ;-)

The instructions are not so easy to understand even for non beginner.
Just call your method

```
PrintStudentDetails(string first, string last, string birthday)
```

from the method

```
static void GetStudentInfo()
```

Good luck to complete the assignment

Comment: thanks!!, yes i didn't exactly know what they wanted. getting there now, thanks !

Comment: 6 - Call the Print methods from within each Get method.

Comment: No, this is not good form. If you are going to call the print function directly from the collection function, why not just print the values in the collection function? If there is no way to get the collected values out of the collection function, the print function will not be useful because it will not be reusable.

Comment: @RboDev: what is this EDX DEV2014x MOOC thing? Is it the Programming with C#  online course at https://www.edx.org/? Looks interesting.